# How do I go about proving a summation is equal to a certain big O?

Tags: summation, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I've been working on my Algorithms homework and figuring out the $\mathcal{O}$, $\Omega$, $\Theta$, etc, of several algorithms. I'm proving them by finding their $c$ and $n_0$ values and all is going well.

However, I've come across my last two problems in the set and I'm struggling figuring out how to do them (and google isn't helping much).

I haven't had to figure out the $\mathcal{O}$/$\Omega$ of summations before.

My last two problems are:

1. $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 2}^{n} \log i \in \Theta\left(n\log n\right)$
2. $\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{n} i^p \in \Theta\left(n^{p + 1}\right),\forall p\ge1$

My question is, How do I show that or how do I start thinking about this?

Comment: 1. [Stirling's approximation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsApproximation.html)

2. [Power sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html)

Comment: For $O$: Note that the left-hand side is always less than the right-hand side. For $\Omega$: this is a bit more tricky, but power sum and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities can be used to prove it

Comment: Another for 1. take exp, use the Gaussian sum then take log.

Comment: Hint for both: Bound the sums as integrals.